# extract a sub directory history in git which was renamed

Tags: git, git-filter-branch

I know that I can extract a history for a given folder for a specified branch in `git` with a command like this:

```
git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter "a sub directory" -- myBranch
```

Unfortunately the subdirectory was renamed at some point in history from `a subdirectory` to `aSubdirectory` for instance. Unfortunately the `filter-branch` stops at the rename.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

```
git filter-branch --prune-empty --index-filter '
  git ls-files -z |
    egrep --invert-match --null-data "^(a subdirectory|aSubdirectory)/" |
      xargs -0 --no-run-if-empty git rm --cached -q

  git ls-files -s | sed -re "s-\t(a subdirectory|aSubdirectory)/-\t-" |
    git update-index --index-info

  git ls-files -z |
    egrep --null-data "^(a subdirectory|aSubdirectory)/" |
      xargs -0 git rm --cached -q
' -- myBranch
```

Renaming files is a high–level operation (ha!), so we break it down into its delete and add components.

The first command in the script deletes everything outside `a subdirectory` or `aSubdirectory`. The second adds everything in those directories into the repository root. Finally, the third completes the move by deleting any files in those directories.

For example, starting with a history of

```
$ git lol --name-status
* 27c7275 (HEAD, myBranch) file2
| A     aSubdirectory/file2
* 39d7e75 mv
| D     a subdirectory/file1
| A     aSubdirectory/file1
* c710654 file1
  A     a subdirectory/file1
```

running the `git filter-branch` command above results in a history of

```
$ git lola --name-status
* da6c7ae (HEAD, myBranch) file2
| A     file2
* d94110a file1
  A     file1
* 27c7275 (refs/original/refs/heads/myBranch) file2
| A     aSubdirectory/file2
* 39d7e75 mv
| D     a subdirectory/file1
| A     aSubdirectory/file1
* c710654 file1
  A     a subdirectory/file1
```

The `refs/original/refs/heads/myBranch` is a backup that, after verifying the result, you can discard with

```
git update-ref -d refs/original/refs/heads/myBranch
```

to leave

```
$ git lola
* da6c7ae (HEAD, myBranch) file2
* d94110a file1
```

**Notes:**

- The commit that renamed the directory disappeared thanks to `--prune-empty`.
- I have no idea how well this will handle rename collisions.
- `git lol` and `git lola` are non–standard but [highly useful aliases](http://blog.kfish.org/2010/04/git-lola.html)

Comment: Thanks for the highly detailed answer. I cannot test it right now but I noticed that the "renaming" is hard-coded into the script. Is there a way to _detect_ renames without having to figure them out by hand?

Comment: @Onur The script does not detect renames by hand. You want an operation equivalent to `--subdirectory-filter`, so for each commit it moves anything in `a subdirectory` or `aSubdirectory` to the repository root and removes anything else.

Comment: I think you got me wrong. I don't want to hardcode the list of names a subdirectory had in the repository. I'm looking for a way to give the command only the current directory name like "aSubdirectory" and let the command figure it out itself that the folder was once known as "a subdirectory".

Comment: @Onur You’re right: I did misunderstand. That is an interesting problem that will require more thought.

Answer (score 0):

I found this useful, but I'm On OSX and had some trouble with @Greg Bacon's solution because xargs and egrep lack some capabilities.
I ended up writing a perl script that I made sure was on the $PATH

```
git filter-branch --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat --index-filter 'git_prune_non_proxy_dirs.pl' -- --all
```

And the perl script looks like this (I guess you could modify it to do all three steps this just does "part one" make sure to use system and not exec for invoking git in that case though)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 

open(LS,"git ls-files|") || die "Failed to git ls-files: $!\n";
my %to_remove=();
while ( <LS> ) {
    chomp;
    if( $_ =~ m#(^adserver-proxy(|-api)/)#) {
    }else{
        my @components = split('/',$_, 2);
        my $path_to_delete = $components[0];
        $to_remove{$path_to_delete}=1;
    }
}
if (%to_remove) { 
    my @cmd=(
        "git","rm","-rfq","--cached","--", keys %to_remove);
    exec(@cmd) || die "Failed to invoke git rm"
}
```